# What is correct interpretation of "p" in R(squared) adjusted formula?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I was looking at a regression problem I have, and I'm using the R(squared) metric to assess my model, in addition to other metrics. I'm aware that R(squared) will always increase as the number of features increase/add more features, which I'm also using the R(squared) adjusted metric to account for this change.

Using the following formula, I'm having doubts about the actual value of p.

[image]

If I have a number of independent variables (a mix between numerical and categorical), should the value of p be based on the number of variables after processing categorical features or not?

Lets say I have 3 variables: Num_1, Cat_1, Cat_2. And Cat_1 is a binary categorical variable, and Cat_2 has 3 unique values. Would the value of p be 4? Since Cat_2 gets encoded into 2 variables. Or is it 3? Not accounting encoding.

Comment: It's not clear from your description how you're representing your data to the model. How many coefficients are you estimating? If both `cat_1` and `cat_2` are encoded using 1-hot encoding, then $p = 1 + 2 + 3$. But if `cat_1` is binary encoded and `cat_2` is dummy-encoded, then $p = 1 + 1 + 2$ (including `num_1`). If `cat_3` has only 3 values, but those values are numerical (e.g. -0.5, 1.2, 101.7), then `cat_3` only estimates one coefficient, so `cat_3` only counts as 1 for computing $p$.

Comment: I think it's dummy-encoded. I was going to mention the dummy variable trap, but did not find necessary as per OP's examples. But, yes, I believe it should be clarified better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the number of independent variables *entering* into the regression model.; therefore it's the number after any preprocessing step performed. In this case it is 4, assuming you're using dummy-encoding as per your examples suggest.

Comment: +1 Phrased informally, the regression model doesn’t know or care how you wound up with the features, just that there are parameters to estimate.